# how to retrieve S3-hosted images with PHP+CURL without getting SignatureDoesNotMatch?

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3

I've got a PHP-managed site that is pulling content from a Posterous blog via an RSS feed. In this feed are images with Posterous URLs, but when I retrieve them they redirect to Amazon S3 URLs.

Within php I'm using curl to try to pull the images and cache them locally, using code from PHP's CURL manual page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php#93163 verbatim. It handles the redirects to S3 some of the time, but unpredictably, instead of retrieving the image, it will return an XML file with a SignatureDoesNotMatch error.

What causes this? And what can I do to prevent the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the failures are intermittent, it's probably something to do with the file(key) names. A common culprit is spaces in the filenames.

You'll need to URL Encode them or replace spaces with `%20`

Comment: That was it - or at least the crux of it. The AWS signatures generated by Posterous intermittently contain special characters (%2B, %3D, and so on). In the [get_url() function I used](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php#93163), it was calling urldecode, which converted all of these special characters back to their un-urlencoded values, and never urlencoded them again, so the CURL request failed. In my case, simply removing the urldecode works.

Comment: @kinder - great stuff. I have run into numerous issues with special characters in the key and bucket names in the past.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand SignatureDoesNotMatch is the error you get when you are not authorised to access the resource. are you providing the necessary credentials?